# use message driven bean to get message from topic apache apollo

Tags: java, activemq-classic, apollo

I create java app that uses message driven bean(MDB) to get message from topic apache apollo through resource adapter activeMq 5.10 in glassfish. When i use apache ActiveMQ, it works fine but not work with apache apollo. I use mqtt to send message with topic a and mqtt to listen at that topic and gets the message. But when i use MDB to listen , it can't get any message. I see apollo console, tab virtual host -> topic. I click the topic that use to send and receive message. That topic has consumer and producer, "Enqueued: 2 items / 2.72 kb" but consumer "Transfers = 0". I don't know how to do MDB work with Apollo.

apollo.xml

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/activemq/apollo">
  <notes>
       The default configuration with tls/ssl enabled.
  </notes>
  <log_category console="console" `enter code here`security="security"connection="connection"audit="audit"/>
  <authentication domain="apollo"/>
  <!-- Give admins full access -->
  <access_rule allow="admins" action="*"/>
  <access_rule allow="*" action="*"/> 
  <virtual_host id="benchmark-broker">
     <host_name>benchmark-broker</host_name>
     <host_name>localhost</host_name>
     <host_name>127.0.0.1</host_name> 
     <authentication enabled="false"/>
     <topic slow_consumer_policy="block" >
       <subscription tail_buffer="4k"/>
     </topic>
  </virtual_host>
  <web_admin bind="http://0.0.0.0:9022"/>
  <web_admin bind="https://127.0.0.1:61681"/>
  <connector id="tcpMqtt" bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:7521" connection_limit="60000">
      <mqtt max_message_length="104857600"  />
  </connector>
 <connector id="tcpOpenwire" bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:9021" connection_limit="60000">
     <openwire tight_encoding="false" tcp_no_delay="true"/>
 </connector>
</broker>
```

Code to publish message:

```
    String user = env("APOLLO_USER", "admin");
    String password = env("APOLLO_PASSWORD", "password");
    String host = env("APOLLO_HOST", "192.168.0.54");
    int port = Integer.parseInt(env("APOLLO_PORT", "7521"));
    final String destination = arg(args, 0, "cuongdm17");
    int messages = 1;
    String body = "test";

    MQTT mqtt = new MQTT();
    mqtt.setHost(host, port);
    mqtt.setUserName(user);
    mqtt.setPassword(password);

    FutureConnection connection = mqtt.futureConnection();
    connection.connect().await();
    final LinkedList<Future<Void>> queue = new LinkedList<Future<Void>>();
    UTF8Buffer topic = new UTF8Buffer(destination);
    for (int i = 1; i <= messages; i++) {
        queue.add(connection.publish(topic, msg, QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE, false));
    }
```

MDB :

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "cuongdm17")
})
public class Cuongdm17 extends AmiAbstractMQTTProcessor implements MessageListener, Serializable {

static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AmiMonitorProcessor.class.getName());

public Cuongdm17() {
}

@Override
protected Logger getLogger() {
    return logger;
}

/**
 * Handler MQTT (already transcript to JMS) messages from DCU Device
 *
 * @param message
 */
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        info("cuongdm17");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error("Error when processing onMessage, error message=" + e.getMessage() + ", message trace=" + message, e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void receiveMessage(MQTTPayloadData payload) throws Exception {
    info("cuongdm17");
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Current-Info Processor";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if Apollo has a great modern core, it does not have all features of ActiveMQ. While ActiveMQ supports mixing wire protocols between producers/consumers - Apollo does not. If you switch to Apollo, you much also switch to consuming using MQTT in your case.

Comment: i see, when i try using ActiveMQConnectionFactory to create consumer and producer like example of apollo, MDB can get the message. MQTT maybe do not work with MDB in apollo or there is something wrong in my code.

Comment: MDB uses the OpenWire protocol - that is, using the JMS interface/sematics. So, no you can't use that with MQTT messages in Apollo